# amazon sdk android sample code showing exception

Tags: android, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I am trying to run sample code in aws-android-sdk-1.4.4. I have edited the secret key and access key as specified in the document. But its showing the following error:

11-15 17:22:09.835: I/AmazonHttpClient(2141): Unable to execute HTTP request: Unable to resolve host "s3.amazonaws.com": No address associated with hostname

Could ny one pls help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you included following permissions in your manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I help maintain the AWS SDK for Android.  Our samples should work out of the box, so please make sure your device/simulator is able to connect to the internet by launching the web browser or using another application.  You may want to restart the emulator if it is unable to make outbound connections.

Also, please make sure that you don't enter in any additional spaces when entering your access or secret key.

**Update 2014-10-07:** With the update to version 2 of the AWS SDK for Android, we've made the decision to require importing of the SDK jar files into all samples instead of including them in the repo. All samples have README files that should indicate all the necessary steps to get started with that particular sample.

Comment: The device is able to connect to the internet by using other application. And i also verified there is no additional space in the access and secret key. But it is not working for me.

Comment: @ElezabethMathew Is your emulator running in a language other than American English?  We have seen some issues in the past with S3_Uploader when using in different languages.  Have you tried other samples?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was able to run s3Uploader some how. But now when i run S3_SimpleDB_SNS_SQS_Demo with same secret key and access key, It shows a dialog saying access denied.

Comment: @ElezabethMathew It sounds like you may have copied the keys incorrectly.  Please make sure you're using the correct keys for your account as supplied by the AWS website.  Also make sure that the keys in the AwsCredentials.properties file are not quoted or having trailing spaces.

Comment: I am using the same key that i used to run S3Uploader. I also verified that its neither quoted nor having trailing spaces. When i run S3_SimpleDB_SNS_SQS_Demo and choose Simple Storage(s3) ->Async Transfer -> Start Upload, it shows as follows:   11-20 14:32:55.669: E/(1854): Status Code: 403, AWS Service: Amazon S3, AWS Request ID: EFDD9333E2CB940B, AWS Error Code: AccessDenied, AWS Error Message: Access Denied, S3 Extended Request ID: F0eOXyoztqHlZA8jgjlteBH5VpLDb1AbyXosGm8Q6wBxsJHLyjkUjBz9lWq2CdAU. [My acccess key dont have the permission to create bucket]

Comment: Is this the root access and secret key for your account or an IAM user?  If you go to list buckets, do you also see an error, or only on create bucket?  If you try to access any of the other services in the Demo app, do you also receive an error?

Comment: I am not able to list the bucket also. I receive error on accessing other services in Demo app.

Comment: Sorry to keep asking this, but could you please make sure that you've copied the keys correctly from the AWS website?
https://portal.aws.amazon.com/gp/aws/securityCredentials

Comment: I am using access and secret key for an IAM user. Am sure the keys are correct.

Comment: I am using multipart upload using Transfermanager class. Could you pls tell me how can i restart the upload if the upload process get interrupted due to netwok failure.

Comment: @ElezabethMathew If you are using an IAM user, are you certain that the user has a policy that allows use of S3?

As for resuming uploads TransferManager, I'm afraid that's not currently supported.  It will retry individual part uploads if they fail for some reason, but is not designed to resume partial uploads. You'll want to make sure you regularly check for partial uploads as these will still count against your S3 usage.

We'll investigate the feasibility of adding resuming uploads with a future update.

Comment: I am able to upload using S3_Uploader. Could you suggest a way to handle the situation, when i am uploading a large video. After uploading almost 3/4th of the video, the netwok fails. So if i want to complete uploading, do i have to upload the video from the beginning.

Comment: I would like to know more about TransferManager class. Especially about the call back methods, after uploading using TransferManager.

Comment: @ElezabethMathew I'm glad you're now able to use the uploader. Unfortunately with the current setup if you want to resume, you may be better off implementing your own multipart upload. Do you have specific questions about the TransferManager?  I might suggest opening a new question with your specific questions.

Comment: But i am not able to run S3_SimpleDB_SNS_SQS_Demo. Could you pls see the question in the following link about Transactionmanager: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13577384/how-to-get-notified-when-the-upload-is-complete-while-using-transactionmanager-c

Comment: @ElezabethMathew I'm sorry you are still encountering errors.  It would be helpful if you could list the errors you are encountering and any steps you took to resolve the issue with the S3_Uploader, perhaps again as a new question.

Comment: They do not work out of the box, all the files of CognitoSyncDemo show classes (DataSet and others) to be not found. You have to import the aws-android-sdk-2.1.1-cognito.jar into the project for most of them to disappear. Still others remain, no idea how you get things done.

Comment: @Sicp I'm sorry you're encountering issues. Please open a new question here on SO or over on [our forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=88) and someone will be happy to assist you.

Comment: @Sicp We've updated the GitHub repo with updated versions of the projects to address an issue related to the FacebookSDK. Please update your checkout and if you still have issues, post a question with any errors. Also note that unlike when this answer was first written, it is necessary to import the necessary jar files.