# How to get notified when the upload is complete while using TransferManager Class?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, transactionmanager

I am using TransferManager to upload a video. As TransferManager is asynchronous, How can i get notified when the upload is successfully completed?

Answer (score 1):

Using TransferManager for uploading returns a [Upload](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSAndroidSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/Upload.html) object, which is a subclass of [Transfer](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSAndroidSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/Transfer.html).  This object has methods for polling for status (`isDone`, `getProgress`) or you can also register a [ProgressListener](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSAndroidSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/ProgressListener.html) to receive events as the transfer is processed.